# How do i calculate the percentages progress, i'm getting negative number all the time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The result I get is all the time a negative number.

In a new form, I added a long variable:

```
long totalBytes = 0;
public static int fileuploadpercentages = 0;
```

Then I have this event:

```
private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
{            
    stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
    if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
    {
        fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
        uploadstatus = "uploading file";
    }
}
```

When I'm using a break point on the line:

```
fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
```

I see that BytesSent = 786432
Then I continue.

Now I see that BytesSent = 1572864

Next BytesSent = 2359296

The problem is totalBytes all the time 0

What I want to get is the percentages progress 1% 2% 3%...untill 100% if it's not possible in jumps of ones 1% 2% 3% then other jumps but i want to get in fileuploadpercentages the percentages upload progress.

The negative number i get in fileuploadpercentages is: -2147483648

This event is part of the youtube file upload I'm using.
This is my upload method to youtube: In this method I register to the 1videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged1 event.

```
UserCredential uc = null;
private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
{
    try
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
        video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            const int KB = 0x400;
            var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
            videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
            videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            videosInsertRequest.Upload();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception errors)
    {
        string errorss = errors.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you ever setting `totalBytes` to the value for the file being uploaded?

Comment: make sure to set the totalBytes value

Comment: Right i set now the value of totalByte but: It's working showing the percentages but for some reason it stop on 89% it keep uploading and after it's getting to 89% i know it finished uploading but the value in fileuploadpercentages stay on 89% this is the steps of percentages i see when using break point on the line fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100); 13,25,38,51,63,76,89 I guess it can't show the percentages in steps of 1% 2% 3% but why it's getting only to 89% ?

Answer (score 0):

Complete with this:

```
totalBytes = fileStream.Length;
videosInsertRequest.Upload();
```

Comment: It's working showing the percentages but for some reason it stop on 89% it keep uploading and after it's getting to 89% i know it finished uploading but the value in fileuploadpercentages stay on 89%   this is the steps of percentages i see when using break point on the line fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100); 13,25,38,51,63,76,89  I guess it can't show the percentages in steps of 1% 2% 3% but why it's getting only to 89% ?

Comment: Oh ok look at this:

if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
{
....
}

You need to handle when completed.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `totalBytes = fileStream.Length;` before `videosInsertRequest.Upload();`